# Select one row from this table and all related rows from other table

Tags: mysql

**table user**

id   |  name          |  address

3    |  Jacko         |  33A Herewini

**table user_photo**

id   |  userid        |  thumb         |   full

1    |  3             |  3k1j_thumb.jpg| 3k1j.jpg

1    |  3             |  3k1j_thumb.jpg| 3k1j.jpg

2    |  14             |  44r_thumb.jpg| 44r.jpg

2    |  14             |  55t_thumb.jpg| 55t.jpg

2    |  14             |  12f_thumb.jpg| 12f.jpg

I got the user id, I want to select his name and address and all his photos

PS: what tool/software you use to draw the table line (the +---+) ?

Edit: then how would you put the name in a div and all the photos in a ul

my html look like this

```
<div class='name'></div>

...600 elements...

<ul class='photos'></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the address, you can just query that table:

```
   SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 3
```

To get the photos, you can query the user photo table:

```
   SELECT * FROM user_photo WHERE userid = 3
```

If you want to get everything at once, you can join the two tables together on the user id:

```
   SELECT * FROM user u
   LEFT JOIN user_photo up ON up.userid = u.id
   WHERE u.id = 3
```

Note though that the address info will of course be duplicated on every row

Comment: how would you put the name in a <div> and all the photos in a <ul> ?

Comment: @runrunforest - just iterate through the rows and only display the name from the first row, ignoring it on the rest of them (since you know they will all have the same name).  Or you can just do two queries, which would be fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about `LEFT JOIN`, see e.g. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-select.html

```
SELECT * FROM user AS u LEFT JOIN user_photo AS p ON p.userid = u.id
```

Adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To combine the results of two tables linked by one column (id in this case), you would use a `JOIN`.

You can read up on JOINs in the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT *
FROM   user u
       LEFT OUTER JOIN user_photo up ON up.userid = u.id
```